# Ignite returning Failed to run reduce query locally

Tags: java, sql, database, ignite

Hi I am executing Ignite SQL which has subqueries containing aggregate functions, group bys and joins. same query with same set of data works sometimes and sometimes it is throwing exception like "Failed to run reduce query locally". I am currently using Ignite 2.5.0 it is said that similar issue has been fixed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3860
 but still getting same issue in my DEV environment.

Comment: Could you share a full stacktrace of the problem. This problem definitely doesn't have something in common with the issue you've shared

Comment: Also, can you please share the SQL statement?